# Traverse(get) elements wrapped inside <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have got something like:

```
<a class="feature category">
            <div class="feature-txt left">
                <p id="first">innerHTML</p>
            </div>
            <div class="feature-go left center">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-fw"></i>
            </div>
        </a>
```

On clicking  I want to get text inside p tag, but:

```
$('.category').on('click', function() {
            alert($(this).find("p").innerHTML);
        });
```

is not working. How can I get it?

Comment: Have you tried jQuery's `.text()` method? `$(this).find("p").eq(0).text()`

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).find("p")` returns the jquery object of dom element. you can not use javascript methods on them directly.

1) Either convert the object to javascript

```
$('.category').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).find("p")[0].innerHTML);
});
```

2) or use `.text()` or `.html()` methods of jquery

```
$('.category').on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).find("p").text());
    });
```

Comment: Oh, it worked. So p tag is indeed child node of a. Or maybe find() is not just for childnodes?

Comment: it is a child node as jquery object. you need to convert them to js object for using js methods on them.

Answer (score 0):

use below code . use .text() or .html() functions of jquery

```
  $('.category').on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).find("p").text());
  });
```

or

```
 $('.category').on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).find("p").html());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

*won't work because div and p are not child nodes of a tag.*

You are still misunderstood it. As per your markup, one can easily says that `div` and `p` are the child nodes of anchor.

Issue is `.innerHTML` javascript method you are binding this method to a jQuery object, while you need to have a DOM Node to use it, so either you can use `[0]` suffix to convert it to the DOM Node or use `.get(0)` for the same in jquery.

To use `innerHTML`

```
$('.category').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).find("p")[0].innerHTML);
    alert($(this).find("p").get(0).innerHTML);
});
```

or another way is to use `.html(), .text()` of jQuery which also does the same:

```
$('.category').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).find("p").html());
    alert($(this).find("p").text());
});
```

Comment: I just figured out it . And changed question. I was just a bit confused.